# Using `gpplot2` to replicate `sciplot` using multiple factor variables

Tags: r

I'm a big fan of using `sciplot` for experimental data, as I don't have to manually calculate the error bars.  In the past, I've used it to group over two factor variables, such that:

```
plot1<-bargraph.CI(
  df$factor1,   #categorical factor for the x-axis
  df$y,         #numerical DV for the y-axis
  df$factor2    #grouping factor
)
```

However, I now have the need to group over THREE factor variables. The `sciplot` documentation indicates that this isn't possible in `sciplot.`

So, now comes the requisite time to ask...how in the world do I do this with `ggplot2`? Specifically, is there a parsimonious way to generate a graph with error bars over 3 factor variables?  I've poked around the web, and keep coming up short when it comes to finding an elegant solution.

Sample data below:

```
factor1          factor2             factor3     y
More expensive   Least important     Blue        1
Less expensive   Most important      Blue        0
Same cost        Least important     Red         1
More expensive   Least important     Red         0
Less expensive   Most important      Red         1
Same cost        Least important     Blue        1
More expensive   Least important     Red         1
Less expensive   Least important     Blue        0
Same cost        Most important      Red         1
```

Comment: When you say *group over three factor variables* do you mean the grouping factor contains 3 variables or somehow you want to include a third factor variable between the x-axis grouping factor?

Comment: The latter - I want to include a third factor variable between the x-axis grouping factor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replicate (to a degree) `sciplot` by using two calls to `stat_summary`.

You can incorporate two factor levels as an `interaction` (using `interaction`) or using faceting.

I will use the `ToothGrowth` which is shipped in the datasets package with base R.

```
# add third factor
ToothGrowth$F3 <- letters[1:2]
# coerce dose to a factor
ToothGrowth$dose <- factor(ToothGrowth$dose, levels = c(0.5,1,2))

# interaction on the x axis
 ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(y = len, x = interaction(supp, F3))) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = 'mean', fun.ymin = function(x) 0, geom = 'bar', 
    aes(fill =dose), position = 'dodge') +
  stat_summary(fun.ymin = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x), 
    fun.ymax = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x),  position ='dodge', 
    geom = 'errorbar', aes(group = dose))
```

[image]

```
# facetting on the third factor
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(y = len, x = supp )) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = 'mean', fun.ymin = function(x) 0, geom = 'bar', 
   aes(fill =dose), position = 'dodge') +
  stat_summary(fun.ymin = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x), 
               fun.ymax = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x), position ='dodge', 
               geom = 'errorbar', aes(group = dose))+
  facet_wrap(~F3)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(y = len, x = supp)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = 'mean', fun.ymin = function(x) 0, 
               geom = 'bar', aes(fill =interaction(dose, F3)), 
               position = 'dodge') +
  stat_summary(fun.ymin = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x), 
               fun.ymax = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x), 
               position ='dodge', geom = 'errorbar', 
               aes(fill =interaction(dose, F3)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually this *is* possible in sciplot. Below are two solutions the first by specifying the grouping factors as a list and the second replicating the faceting solution from ggplot.

```
library(sciplot)

## add third factor as in above example
ToothGrowth$F3 <- letters[1:2]

## Adding group as a list
bargraph.CI(response=len, x.factor=supp, group=list(dose, F3),
            data=ToothGrowth, legend=TRUE, x.leg=14, xlim=c(0,19),
            err.width=0.025)
```

[image: output]

```
## Using "panels"
par(mfrow=c(1,2), xpd=NA)
bargraph.CI(response=len, x.factor=supp, group=dose, data=ToothGrowth,
            subset=F3=="a", xlab="a", cex.lab=1.25,
            legend=TRUE, x.leg=7.5, err.width=.025)
bargraph.CI(response=len, x.factor=supp, group=dose, data=ToothGrowth,
            subset=F3=="b", xlab="b", cex.lab=1.25, err.width=.025)
```

[image: output]

Comment: (+1) You can post the images now